# batch file and localhost:5000

Tags: node.js, batch-file, localhost

I'm trying to write a batch file that would initiate my TCP-server and a server with these commands.
So far I have:

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
@echo off

cd "C:path\to\my\foler"
REM Next command opens tcp-server.js and server
start node tcp-server.js
start node start.js  
start /d "C:path\to\my\foler" chrome.exe localhost:5000
```

Now, these above start the TCP-server and my server too,  i. e., if on Chrome enter `localhost:5000` etc. it does start to work, however:

- I want to automatically start displaying the page I want it to run from.
- Also, I want the two nodejs files `tcp-server.js` and `start.js` run minimized.

Comment: Did you read the help for the `START` command? Might help you answer some of your questions.

Comment: thansk for your comment - i found a solution myself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

again - i found myself a solution to it - hope it helps someone someday! :)

```
 @echo off

 cd "C:\path\to\the\folder"
 start /min node tcp-server.js
 start /min node start.js  
 start /d "C:\to\the\folder" chrome.exe 
 http://localhost:5000/folder/page.html%~n1%~x1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but I hope this also helps someone one day, with a similar problem, so they too can problem solve their solution off the one above like I did:

```
@echo off
start "C:/" chrome.exe http://localhost:40120
pause
```